# Why was it the Junker that proved to Yumemi that she was "malfunctioning"?

Tags: planetarian

In episode 5 of *planetarian*, after

> the crab mech blows the lower half of her body off,

Yumemi tells the Junker (or "kuzuya" / 屑屋; I don't know what the usual translation is) that the reason she believed she was slightly "malfunctioning" is that she kept coming to the conclusion that no people would ever come to see her again. So the Junker's arrival did indeed prove her conclusion to be "faulty".

But the Junker *isn't* the first person since the war to see her, is he? There's a flashback in episode 1 where we see some old guy telling the Junker about how met "a robot" who I think it is safe to say was Yumemi. Judging from his irritation, Yumemi must've been awake (not asleep/charging), so I would think that Yumemi would remember the old guy.

Is this a plot hole? Or, perhaps, a defect of the anime adaptation?

(*planetarian* being a small and mostly self-contained work, I think it should be possible to identify whether or not this is a plot hole with a good degree of certainty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a plot hole? Or, perhaps, a defect of the anime adaptation?

Both. Adaptation-induced plot hole.

The flashback with the old guy is anime-only. No such scene is in the VN and Junker never heard about robot like Yumemi.